# ActiveMQ autodiscovery all deployed queues and topics using JNDI

Tags: activemq-classic, jndi

Is it possible to discover all ActiveMQ queues and topics via JNDI? It was possible to fetch them all with HornetQ using the "list" method. I would like to implement a JMS client for multiple brokers and don't like to pre-configure all queues in jndi.properties.

```
Properties props = new Properties();    
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "tcp://localhost:61616");

Context context = new InitialContext(props);

NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> names = ctx.list(jndiPrefix);
```

Answer (score 0):

The activemq initialContext factory implements a simple hashmap that is unrelated to the broker because the broker will create any destination on demand unless authorization prevents that behaviour.
You can use the dynamic contexts - dynamicQueues/FOO.BAR or dynamicTopics/FOO.BAR to access a destination named FOO.BAR without any additional configuration.
see: jndi-support in the doc[1](http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html) for some more detail.